# Optical Coupler

Tags: optics

i have two modems, each modem Tx signal is converted to fiber optics.

can I combine the two Tx signals (signal A and signal B) with an optical coupler?
At each time data is transmitted by only on one of the modem Tx
so that when :

A transmitting data and B doesn't transmit anything at the output of the coupler I'll receive A?
and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible as per What's answer below. You are running in half-duplex mode (only one end transmitting at a time). Just make sure that there is no handshaking (XON / XOFF, for instance) going on in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, but I suggest you do a bit of really elementary Googling before you ask this sort of question. Using "fiber optic splitter" or "fiber optic coupler will get you lots candidates. [Newport, for instance](http://www.newport.com/1x2-and-2x2-Singlemode-Fiber-Couplers/835446/1033/info.aspx) has just what you need.

Comment: And other sources have them for a LOT less money (I lost a lot of respect for newport (I used a lot of their hardware on optical tables decades ago) when I had to build a communications fiber optics system on a budget - and also when I read their truly out of touch advice to soak connectors in isopropyl before use. FIS (only a mostly happy customer) has these for less than half the lowest priced newport version. http://www.fiberinstrumentsales.com/assemblies/couplers-splitters-wdm-s-plc-s.html

Comment: Wont the laser of B will increase the noise levels when modem A is  working?